# Problema de concorrência em aplicação java web

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, ejb, transações

Boa noite pessoal,

Vejam o seguinte código:

Controller

```
@WebServlet("/testConcurrency")
public class TestConcurrency extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6124392524678396101L;

    @EJB(name="bs/UsuarioBS/local")
    private UsuarioBSLocal usuarioBS;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String emailStr = request.getParameter("email");

        System.out.println("[Inicio] usuarioBS.testConcurrency();");

        try {
            usuarioBS.testConcurrency(emailStr);
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("[Fim] usuarioBS.testConcurrency();");
    }
}
```

BS

```
@Stateless(name="business/UsuarioBS")
public class UsuarioBS implements UsuarioBSLocal {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UsuarioBS.class);

    @EJB(name="dao/EmailDAO/local")
    private EmailDAOLocal emailDAO;

    @Override
    public void testConcurrency(String emailStr) throws BusinessException {
        try {
            boolean existeEmail = emailDAO.existeEmail(emailStr);

            System.out.println("Existe email ["+ emailStr +"]? " + existeEmail);

            if (!existeEmail) {
                Email email = new Email(emailStr);
                email.setPessoa(new Pessoa(1l));
                email.setTipoEmail(TipoEmail.PRINCIPAL);

                try {
                    System.out.println("Waiting...");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                emailDAO.inserir(email);

                System.out.println("Email ["+ emailStr +"] inserido!");
            }
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Se eu chamar duas vezes a url /testConcurrent?email=email@server.com.br em menos de 5 segundos ele irá inserir o email duas vezes, o que não pode ocorrer.

Ps: o Thread.sleep() está somente para ilustrar o problema. Em outros lugares de minha aplicação eu também chamo o método emailDAO.existeEmail().

Como eu posso resolver isso?

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código contém alguns pontos, que merecem as seguintes observações:

- Não utilize operações de thread em um container, a não ser que você vá gerenciar todo o lifecycle  da Thread que você mesmo tenha disparado (ex: [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)), ainda mais neste caso que você tem um bean Stateless, pode ocorrer resultados imprevisíveis referente à concorrência. [REF.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202492/thread-sleep-in-an-ejb)
- Supondo que seu `Thread.sleep()` estivesse OK, note que se você chamar a segunda vez em menos de 5 segundos (como você citou) você já terá verificado a existência do email no banco E não terá inserido nada ainda. Logo na segunda chamada, ainda não terá nada gravado, pois a primeira chamada estará ainda travada. Isso não é concorrência, é apenas o modelo que você está usando.
- Mesmo retirando `Thread.sleep()` você ainda poderia ter questões de concorrência a nível de transação (aqui estamos falando de milisegundos). Esse ponto é importante definir o comportamento esperado pois a transação será 'comitada' dependendo do tipo atributo que estiver sendo utilizado ([Mais detalhes aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/6nisfjnao/index.html)). Logo esse passo é importante para determinar questões de [Locking](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock) do JPA.

Comment: O Thread.sleep() foi inserido somente para ilustrar o problema. Aqui eu estou utilizando o JDBC. Já cheguei a ler sobre os atributos de transação, mas sinceramente não entendi muito bem. Como seria implementado na prática com base nesse código?